# Blank screen React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am setting up a react-leaflet map and I am following the setup on their website. But whenever I compile the site the screen is blank and there is no error.

> App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import './App.css'; 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer 

    center={43.38621, -79.83713} 
    zoom="13" 
    scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    
  </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

> App.css

```
.leaflet-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

> Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `MapContainer'`s center should be an array `center={[43.38621, -79.83713]}`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to give height to MapContainer too, not only to the div containing the map.

Also, as @kboul said, the center coordinates should be an array:

```
<MapContainer 
  center={[43.38621, -79.83713]} 
  zoom="13" 
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
  style={{height: "100vh"}}
>
  <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />

</MapContainer>
```